# Hide/show views in another class

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have the following situation:
[image]

The `SecondViewController` is inside the `FirstViewController`. Now, I want to add another subclass to `FirstViewController`, but from the `secondViewController` class, as in the image: [image]

I've been searching and I don't think that this is possible. I already tried to instantiate the FirstViewController, access the "view to subview" and add as subview, but that wasn't working:

```
FirstViewController *viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:[viewController viewToAddAsSubView]];
```

Any tips/solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually possible using NSNotificationCenter.  Example below:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(METHOD:) name:@"LISTEN_TO_VIEW_2" object:nil];
```

The above code should be placed in view 1 to "listen" for view 2 to send it a notification that your method in view 1 should be executed to add/edit whatever you want in view 1.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LISTEN_TO_VIEW_2" object:nil];
```

The code above will send the notification to view 1.  Then in view 1 you'll have a method somewhere like this:

```
-(void)METHOD:(id)sender {
//do something here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Brayden! I’m very grateful to you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is that use SecondViewController's view's superView. This is a very straight forward way.

```
[[self.view superview] insertSubview:theView aboveSubview:self.view];
```

Another way is to use delegate. You can declare a delegate in SecondViewController like

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate : NSObject
{
    - (void)requestInsertView:(UIView*)view aboveView:(UIView*)baseView;
}

@interface SecondViewController <...>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SecondViewControllerDelegate>superViewDelegate;
@end;
```

And modify the FirstViewController's declaration to implement the SecondViewControllerDelegate

```
@interface FirstViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate, ...> 

@implement FirstViewController

- (void)requestInsertView:(UIView*)view aboveView:(UIView*)baseView
{
    [self.view insertView:view aboveSubview:baseView];
}
@end;
```

After the SecondViewController is created, set its superViewDelegate to FirstViewController's instance.

At the place you need to add view from SecondViewController, you can call

```
[self.superViewDelegate requestInsertView:view aboveView:self.view];
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, Linden, but Brayden answer it in a simple way.